# MySQL: Table entry representing all 'ids'?

Tags: mysql

I have a single value in a table that I want selected every time a query is made on the table.

Let me break is down.

I have the following entry:
[image]

Instead of making a new entry for every different `user_id`, can I use some kind is primitive to represent ALL `user_id`s instead of specific ids? Example below:
[image]

For reasons that I would rather not take the time to explain, this is what I need. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From a database design perspective, if you need something to be associated with all rows of one table, then you should just remove the foreign key. But if you are modelling a many-to-many relation, you need an extra table. So I guess if you could explain why you need something like this, we could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct in assuming that that means you want `tag_id` linked to every `user_id` (as some sort of a catch-all clause), you have a few ways of going about it. Depending on your application, you can simply request it to add a row for `tag_id = 1` whenever you add a user. If you would, however, want to do it in a single row, well ... it kind of misrepresents the relational model.
You could, presumably use the NULL special "value" (essentially, declare it without a value) and then check in your application logic with

```
WHERE user_id = [uid] OR user_id IS NULL
```

or some such. I'd prefer keeping the relations intact with the former approach, however; you lose foreign keys (although using NULL won't violate the constraint) and similar constraints if you don't.